# Button not center align in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, center-align

Button not centered align in Safari browser only.

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgk6rdp/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="" style=" width: 100%; ">
    <input value="Button" class="center-block" type="submit" style=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-block {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Above problem just come in Safari. In Chrome and Firefox it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you don't set a width for btn:

1. parent - `text-align: center`
2. button child - use `display:inline-block` instead of `display: block`

```css
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
.center-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <input value="Button" class="center-block" type="submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well I used slighter different and cleaner version as here http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgk6rdp/18/